# I want to create a table in hive which contains 2 columns of type Map<string,string>

Tags: hadoop, hive

These are my column names -

```
String A;
String B;
String State;
Map<String, String> C;
Map<String, String> D;
Integer Version;
Long LastUpdatedTime;
Long TimeToLive;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ddb_ttl 
(A string, 
B string, 
State string, 
C map<string,string>, 
D map<string,string>, 
Version bigint, 
LastUpdatedTime bigint, 
TimeToLive bigint
) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "TTDCS", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "A:A,B:B,State:State,C:C,D:D,Version:Version,LastUpdatedTime:LastUpdatedTime,TimeToLive:TimeToLive");
```

This is the command I use to create external table using hive.

I keep getting this error -

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Only one column can be mapped to item map type map<string,string>)

I have tried removing D from the table and it works. The problem is that there are 2 columns that are of map<string,string>. Is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Amazon-emr.  [Here's the documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-emr-release-guide/blob/main/doc_source/EMR_Hive_Commands.md) you only get [one Map](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/blob/master/emr-dynamodb-hive/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/dynamodb/DynamoDBStorageHandler.java).  Why not just add nullable columns instead of a Map?